# Widgets to switch between screens

Tags: android, widget

I would like to have in my activity the widget like this in the top of that  [screen](https://cdn3.pcadvisor.co.uk/cmsdata/features/3447950/Add_bookmarks_to_home_screen_in_Android_10.png). I do not think about clock, but about that 5 balls, and I want to use it the same way - when I change screen then white ball is changing too. I was looking for information about it on [Android Developer](http://developer.android.com/index.html) but I can't found any tips. What type of widget I have to use or do I have to  write all code for this from zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It calls ViewPagerIndicator 
here is https://github.com/bigsolom/AndroidViewPagerIndicator
 custom ViewPager indicator the mimics nexus-5 launcher style (small circles and the selected page is a bigger circle)
hope that will be helpful